# 2013th powered prime factors

Tags: number-theory

Let $N$ be a positive integer. Prove that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n^{2013}-n^{20}+n^{13}-2013$ has at least $N$ distinct prime factors.

factorize the polynomial for some special n does no seem to be working

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My mistake. Misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint/start:** If $P(x)$ is an integer polynomial, and $m,n$ are relatively prime, and $m\mid P(a)$ and $n\mid P(b)$ then there exists $c$ so that $mn\mid P(c)$. (Why?)

So, all you need to show is that there are infinitely many primes $p$ so that the polynomial $x^{2013}-x^{20}+x^{13}-2013$ has a root modulo $p$.

You can use a similar approach to Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes to prove this, but it is a little tricky.